# One-Dimensional Heat Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have the 1-D heat equation

$\frac{\partial w}{\partial t} -\frac{\partial^{2} w}{\partial x^{2}} =0$
$-\pi < x < \pi$

With Initial and Boundary Conditions:
    $w(x,0)=0$
    $w(\pi,t)-w(-\pi,t) = 2\pi$
    $w_{x}(\pi,t) - w_{x}(\pi,t)=0$

I've been using separation of variables 
where $w(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$
and getting solutions for all 3 scenarios where 
$\lambda >0 , \lambda <0 ,\lambda =0$

for $\frac{T'}{T} =\frac{X''}{X}=-\lambda$

I'm not sure if I'm missing a boundary condition I can derive or what to do with the 3 solutions I've obtained so far?

Answer (score 1):

Define a new equation in terms of $v = w(x,t)-x$. This function satisfies
$$
         v_t - v_{xx}=0 \\
         v(x,0)=-x \\
         v(\pi,t)-v(-\pi,t) = u(\pi,t)-u(-\pi,t)-\pi+(-\pi)=0 \\
         v_x(\pi,t)-v_x(-\pi,t)= 0.
$$
This is an equation with homogeneous boundary conditions; so separation of variables succeeds. The substitution moves the inhomogeneity to an initial condition, which is just fine.